# How can I get rid of bracket's when generating random combined text strings in python 3.8?

Tags: string, random, combinations, python-3.8

I need to randomize output and combine them (as text) ,but I keep geting these bracket's that are unappealing. How can I get rid of the bracket's when using random draw?

I am running Linux Ubuntu.

I originally just used + but eventually ran into the problem of wanting a random result.
So...I discovered importing random and got 1 random draw based on my parameter's.

Here is my code.

```
import random

a= ["Dragon", "Tofu" , "Music"]
b= ["January", "Tree", "Book"]

x = random.sample(a,1)
y = random.sample(b,1)
c = x + y


print(c)
print(f' {x} {y}')
```

I tried printing c. Which still print's the bracket's?
I tried the addition...operator? I believe it is called? (I am new to python.)
I tried the f-string and...nope.

Here is what happens:
['Dragon', 'Tree']
['Dragon'] ['Tree']

Versus the desired outcome:

Dragon Tree

(and so on.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want to get one single random value, you should use `random.choice()`.

Comment: After playing around and looking into random.choice() (I ran into random.choices first.) I figured out all I needed to do was replace my value my random.sample with your suggestion. Thank's!